# Web Essentials: URL Import on LESS file is adding extra folder navigation

Tags: css, less, web-essentials

I'm trying to import a less file into another less file but it doesn't seem to be working because the LESS compiler in Web-Essentials is doing funny things. The picture is worth 1000 words.

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to import ../Site.less, but the compiler is trying to import ../../Site.less.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this figured out. I was/am still having the same issue. My file structure was,

/Content/LESS/css

I changed my Custom output directory (Tools > Options > Web Essentials / LESS) to ../css. Now my file structure is

/Content/css

I had to change my file pathing to match the new structure, but am no longer getting the additional folder escape.